# Check if table inherits from other table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, inheritance

In PostgreSQL for these tables

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name            text,
    population      float,
    altitude        int     -- in feet
);

CREATE TABLE cities_capitals (
    state           char(2)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

How can I **programmatically check** whether one of these **tables inherits from another table** or not? (Think information_schema, pg_catalog, ...)

Should be `true` for cities_capitals and `false` for cities.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a catalog table for that: [**`pg_inherits`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-inherits.html).

> The catalog `pg_inherits` records information about table inheritance
> hierarchies. There is one entry for each direct child table in the
> database. (Indirect inheritance can be determined by following chains
> of entries.)

Here's a query that fits your question:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits
   WHERE  inhrelid = 'public.cities_capitals'::regclass
   );
```

`TRUE` if table `cities_capitals` inherits from somewhere, else `FALSE`.
Schema-qualify the name to be sure.

Comment: How should I correlate the inhrelid with a table name in a schema?

Comment: @AxelFontaine: I added to my answer. It's actually quite simple - once you know it. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The following statement will retrieve the tables that `cities` inherits from. If the table does not inherit from another table, the result will be empty:

```
select bt.relname as table_name, bns.nspname as table_schema 
from pg_class ct 
    join pg_namespace cns on ct.relnamespace = cns.oid and cns.nspname = 'public' 
    join pg_inherits i on i.inhrelid = ct.oid and ct.relname = 'cities ' 
    join pg_class bt on i.inhparent = bt.oid 
    join pg_namespace bns on bt.relnamespace = bns.oid
```

Answer (score 0):

From *Postgresql AutoDoc* I found this SQL:

```
SELECT parnsp.nspname AS par_schemaname
    , parcla.relname AS par_tablename
    , chlnsp.nspname AS chl_schemaname
    , chlcla.relname AS chl_tablename
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits
 JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class AS chlcla ON (chlcla.oid = inhrelid)
 JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS chlnsp ON (chlnsp.oid = chlcla.relnamespace)
 JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class AS parcla ON (parcla.oid = inhparent)
 JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS parnsp ON (parnsp.oid = parcla.relnamespace)
```

This is helpful as you can test in both directions with one query.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using [`INHERITS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html)

```
SELECT INHERITS(
  (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'cities_capitals'),
  (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'cities')
)
```

> This will return `t` if `cities_capitals` inherits from `cities` and `f` if not

Comment: Is this function version specific? Using PG14 I got an error indicating the function `INHERITS()` does not exist.