# How to find inherited columns?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get the list of inherited columns in a database. Is there any query that I can use to find this?

I am using PostgreSql 8.3

Comment: This could [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690329/check-if-table-inherits-from-other-table-in-postgresql)

Comment: I have found a way to find the columns that is inherited from parent tables.

Comment: could you post here as an answer?

Comment: Just a side note: 8.3 has been deprecated and is no longer supported. You should plan an upgrade (ideally to 9.2) as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple query to do this:

```
select relname as table_name, attname as column_name 
from pg_class 
join pg_inherits on pg_class.oid = pg_inherits.inhrelid
join pg_attribute on pg_inherits.inhparent = attrelid
where attnum > 0;
```