# Get parent name and schema of a inherited table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

Suppose I have a PostgreSQL table called `master.products` and another called `account.products`. The second one inherits from the first.

Is is possible to create a query to get the parent name and schema of the table `account.products`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this information from the system catalog [`pg_inherits`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-inherits.html).

```
SELECT inhparent::regclass::text
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_inherits
WHERE  inhrelid = 'account.product'::regclass;
```

The name is automatically schema-qualified to make it unambiguous according to the current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777) .

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5480/4)

Related:

- [Check if table inherits from other table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690329/check-if-table-inherits-from-other-table-in-postgresql/7690451#7690451)

About `regclass`:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Comment: Man, you're the boss! I am your fan!